# Create a unchangeable ID

Tags: java, declaration

I'm looking for a way to make an unchangeable ID for an object in java. I think this is something really basic, but I'm a beginner.

If this is my code:

```
public class Node implements IXYNode
{
 String id ="";
 String description ="";
 int x =0;
 int y =0;

 public XYNode(String id, int x, int y)
 {
  this.id=id;
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;

  if(this.id.equals(null) || this.id.isEmpty())
  {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
 }    
}
```

So once it is given, it shouldn't be changable afterwards, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make id as `final` and you cannot assign it again unless it is constructor or in delcaration time.

```
final String id ="";
```

Comment: ok, tried this, but it says in the constructor: "The final field XYNode.id cannot be assigned" so what i don't understand is: 
1. The constructor is reponsible to create a new object, right? And the ID is given as a parameter in the constructor, so i need to declare it in the constructor also or am I wrong?

Comment: `final String id;`. If you assign it when it is declared, you can't reassign it in the constructor.

Comment: @Johnny because you are already doing that the time of declaration `String id ="";` You are allowed to assign it only once.

Comment: ok, but if i create a new object of this class, which ID will be given to this object, if it is final? I think i got a problem in my own logic

Comment: You are going to supply it while object creation and that is all. You cannot change it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
public class Node implements IXYNode
{
 private final String id ="";
 String description ="";
 int x =0;
 int y =0;

 public XYNode(String id, int x, int y)
 {
  this.id=id;
  this.x=x;
```

or i think better way:

```
 public XYNode(int x, int y)
 {
  this.id=UUID.randomUUID().toString(); //randomUUID
  this.x=x;
```